# Using linq to filter child subcollection

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following structure,

Event (PARENT) and has the following fields;  ID, EventName

EventProcess (CHILD) has the following fields; ID EventID(FK), EventProcessName

EventProcessForms (GRANDCHILD) has the following fields; ID, eventProcessID, FormID

Forms- has the following fields, ID, FormName

I am trying to return only Events in which the EventProcess has Forms which are stored in the EventProcessForms Table?

How do i do this using linq to return a collection?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you post your classes so we can understand how you designed your models?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need to go two levels deep:

```
events.Where(
    e => e.EventProcesses.Any(
        ep => ep.EventProcessForms.Any()
        )
    );
```

If either of those properties could be null change to:

```
events.Where(
    e => e.EventProcesses != null && e.EventProcesses.Any(
        ep => ep.EventProcessForms != null && ep.EventProcessForms.Any()
        )
    );
```

If you want to filter to only the *Processes* that have forms you're going to either modify the Event entities using a `foreach` or create new Event objects selecting the filtered processes:

```
events.Select(e=> new Event() {
         ID = e.ID, 
         Name = e.Name, 
         EventProcesses = e.EventProcesses.Where( 
             ep => ep.EventProcessForms.Any())
    .Where(e=>EventProcesses.Any())
    ;
```

Comment: Hi i tried this but it still returns EventProcess in which the EventProcessForms count is 0.

Comment: Do you want the Events or the EventProcesses?

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding, I want the Events to contain EventProcesses which have EventProcessForms, hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I've edited my answer:

```
using (yourDataContext db = new yourDataContext());
{    
    var results = db.Event.Where(e -> e.EventProcess.EventProcessForms.count() > 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
var q = from @event in events 
    where @event.EventProcess.EventForms.Count() > 0 
    select @event;
```

Which could also be represented as:

```
    var q = from @event in events
            where @event.EventProcess.EventForms.Any()
            select @event;
```

Guessing without some sort of actual class to base the properties on...